# openssl tool cannot get certificate from CloudFront, does anyone know why?

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, openssl, amazon-cloudfront

I'm writing a script to check the `SSL` expiry dates of all my domains.

This works for my normal sites:

`echo | openssl s_client -connect $domain:443 2> /dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -enddate`

However it does *not* work for `AWS CloudFront`. I have uploaded my own certificate to `CF` and am using a `CNAME`.

The output is:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
15336:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

Does anyone know why?

I have already tried `-ssl2` and `-no_ssl3` options.

Comment: Try to use [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), i.e. use the `-servername hostname` option of openssl s_client.

Comment: Hi Steffen that works! Thank you! If you want to copy my answer below Ill delete my answer and give you the rep.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding `-servername $domain` fixed it:

`openssl s_client -connect $domain:443 -servername $domain 2> /dev/null < /dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -enddate`

Many thanks to Steffen Ullrich for the comment on the Q.